# Verifying Azure AD token on API

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I use Azure AD B2C to login on a React Native app. This app can make API calls to a CMS (Strapi). Before returning a response, the CMS has to check that the user that makes the request is logged in.

The login part in the app is working fine, this is the data that I get back in the app after logging in:

```json
{
  "tokenType": "Bearer",
  "refreshToken": "...",
  "scope": "offline_access openid",
  "idToken": "...",
  "issuedAt": 1698310667
}
```

The app then sends the idToken in the header `x-activedirectory-token`.

I am lost on how to check the validity of the token in the CMS policy (middleware). I tried the [@azure/msal-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-node) package, but failed to find a method to just check if the token is valid.

[These Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-api?tabs=nodejsgeneric) on the subject setup an Express-Passport middleware, but  Strapi uses a different router (koa), and adding a middleware in middleware seems weird.

The preferred solution would be something like the @azure/msal-node package that can check the token, or some Azure endpoint or something similar.

Maybe I'm overlooking something, because I have little to no Azure AD experience. That being said, any help is very appreciated, since I've been stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: You would typically use standard JSON Web Token authentication libraries to validate the token. MSAL is mostly used to acquire ID/access tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [@juunas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658906/juunas) for pointing me in the right direction. I managed to get the required behaviour by using the jwks-rsa and jsonwebtoken libraries. A code sample of how this worked (based on a code example in the [jsonwebtoken readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)):

```
import {
  verify as verifyJwt,
  type JwtHeader,
  type SigningKeyCallback,
} from "jsonwebtoken";
import jwksClient from "jwks-rsa";

// Gets the cookie information from the discovery document
const client = jwksClient({
  jwksUri: "https://.../discovery/v2.0/keys?p=b2c_1_signin",
});

function getPublicKey(header: JwtHeader, callback: SigningKeyCallback) {
  client.getSigningKey(header.kid, function (err, key) {
    let signingKey = key.getPublicKey();
    if (!signingKey && "rsaPublicKey" in key && key.rsaPublicKey) {
      signingKey = key.rsaPublicKey;
    }

    callback(null, signingKey);
  });
}

// Verify the token with the public key, constructed by the jwksClient
verifyJwt(activeDirectoryToken, getPublicKey, {}, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    // Invalid token
    return;
  }

  // Valid token
});
```

Answer (score 0):

msal should be checking this by default, but if you are looking for a library to do this, look [here](https://jwt.io/libraries).